# GRASS7 r.water.outlet doesn't run correctly in QGIS 2.14.2

Tags: qgis, grass-7.0

I am a new user of GIS software and I am currently facing an issue with the GRASS7 tool `r.water.outlet. I am a beginner with both Linux and GIS. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with QGIS 2.14.2 and GRASS 7.0.3 I downloaded and installed the software by following the instructions of the official QGIS webpage.

I am using GRASS7 `r.watershed` to create a "Drainage" raster that I use as an input for `r.water.outlet`. The second input is the coordinates of vectorial points I want to use to delineate my basins (it would be even better if I could use several points to do so because I need 5 different basins).

This is my `r.water.outlet` interface:

[image]

First thing I noticed: I can't enter decimal numbers, so I lose accuracy for my input points, and the interface is different from the one in the second image for the tool `r.water.outlet` for my version of QGIS.

[image]

Then when I run the process (In my QGIS 2.14.2, the processing plugin version is 2.12.2), I obtain the log:

```
*Démarrage de l'algorithme r.water.outlet - Watershed basin creation program. ...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=lcc +lat_1=44.1 +lat_0=44.1 +lon_0=2.337229166666667 +k_0=0.999877499 +x_0=600000 +y_0=3200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356514.999904194 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="/home/kyle/Bureau/ERM/Data_ERM/GISProjectFolder/Rasters/Drainage_Direction_Watershed.tif" band=1 output=tmp1462467882073 --overwrite -o
g.region -a n=1959000.0 s=1843500.0 e=1038600.0 w=923100.0 res=300
r.water.outlet input=tmp1462467882073 easting="989927" northing="1891138" output=output881924edb38d42189f35bcf5166a0da3 --overwrite
g.region raster=output881924edb38d42189f35bcf5166a0da3
r.out.gdal -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output881924edb38d42189f35bcf5166a0da3 output="/home/kyle/Bureau/ERM/Data_ERM/GISProjectFolder/test_water_outlet.tif"
DÃ©marrage du SIG GRASS ... 
ExÃ©cution de '/home/kyle/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
ATTENTION: Datum non reconnu par GRASS et aucuns paramÃ¨tres trouvÃ©s 
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default 
Projection information updated 
ATTENTION: Datum non reconnu par GRASS et aucuns paramÃ¨tres trouvÃ©s 
ATTENTION: Over-riding projection check 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external terminÃ©. Link to raster map created. 
Description: 
Creates watershed basins from a drainage direction map. 
Keywords: 
raster, hydrology, watershed 
Usage: 
r.water.outlet input=name output=name coordinates=east,north 
[--overwrite] [--help] [--verbose] [--quiet] [--ui] 
Flags: 
--o Autoriser la sortie Ã  Ã©craser les fichiers existants 
--h Afficher le rÃ©sumÃ© d'utilisation 
--v Sortie du module en mode bavard 
--q Sortie du module en mode silence 
--ui Force launching GUI dialog 
Parameters: 
input Name of input drainage direction map 
output Name for output watershed basin map 
coordinates Coordinates of outlet point 
ERROR: r.water.outlet: Sorry, is not a valid parameter 
ERROR: r.water.outlet: Sorry, is not a valid parameter 
ERROR: Required parameter not set: 
(Coordinates of outlet point) 
ERREUR :Couche raster non trouvÃ©e 
ERREUR :Raster map or group not found 
ExÃ©cution de '/home/kyle/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' terminÃ©e. 
Nettoyage des fichiers temporaires ... 
Converting outputs
Charger les couches de résultat
The following layers were not correctly generated.
Basin
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm*
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?  If you need further information, do not hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.water.outlet input=tmp1462467882073 easting="989927" northing="1891138" output=output881924edb38d42189f35bcf5166a0da3 --overwrite
```

I guess the problem comes from 'easting' and 'northing' are not valid parameters, you should substitute them with:

```
coordinates=east,north
```

Written in the help:

```
r.water.outlet input=name output=name coordinates=east,north 
[--overwrite] [--help] [--verbose] [--quiet] [--ui]
```